# How to read binary chunks from file in reverse order?

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, data-structures, kotlin

I need algorithm to read binary file and contracting array with chunks in reverse order.
for example:

```
Input binary data: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
Chunk size: 4
Result: {13 14 15 16} {9 10 11 12} {5 6 7 8} {1 2 3 4}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This would be better asked in a stack exchange site for algorithms, here you would want to present a problem with code for which you want help.  Asking "code my thing for me" is maybe better on Software Engineering Exchange or, look at the list and find a place that matches more what you want.

Comment: Let us know what you've tried. Please add a tag for programming language. Remove tag for 'algorithm' and 'data-structures' as they are irrelevant here.

Comment: What's the expected result if the input size is not divisible by the chunk size? That is, if your input is `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and the chunk size is 4, do you have `[{5, 6}, {1, 2, 3, 4}]`, or `[{3, 4, 5, 6}, {1, 2}]`?

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni Why do you think 'algorithm' is irrelevant here? And why do you think language is required? The algorithm is what's important. Language is irrelevant unless the OP asks specifically for an implementation in a particular language.

Comment: Also, to Dmitry: Do you expect this to work when the file's data is too large to fit into memory? That makes the problem significantly more difficult.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linq Approach (Inefficient due to `GroupBy` & `Reverse`, but I prefer Linq regardless):

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };

int chunkSize = 4;

var chunkedBytes = bytes.Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
                        .GroupBy(i => i.Index / chunkSize)
                        .Select(i => i.Select(j => j.Value))
                        .Reverse().ToList();
```

Using old fashioned Looping:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 };

int chunkSize = 4;

var chunkedBytes = new List<byte[]>();

int offset = bytes.Length % chunkSize;
for (int i = bytes.Length - 1; i >= 0; i -= chunkSize)
{
    byte[] tempBytes = new byte[i < chunkSize - 1 ? offset : chunkSize];
    int index = 0;

    for (int j = tempBytes.Length - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        tempBytes[index++] = bytes[i - j];

    chunkedBytes.Add(tempBytes);
}
```

Comment: It's not me edited tags for the first time, anyway syntax for basic expressions is very close in general purpose languages.

Comment: Thanks for Linq especially

Answer (score 2):

It's not a great question as you are not showing some effort from your own side.

But as you added `[kotlin]`, this is simple to write in Kotlin:

```
val input = byteArrayOf( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16 )
val result = input.asList().chunked(4).reversed()
```

(Note that this solution isn't great on memory consumption in the JVM but that could be solved by optimizing the built-in `chunked` function for byte arrays.

Comment: Thanks, Kotlin library is nicely concise.